# Cannot delete an existing service using sc command: The specified service does not exist as an installed service

Tags: windows-service

I want to delete `MyNewService`, but when I type in

```
sc delete MyNewService
```

I simply can't delete it because there is no such servic, due to

> "the Specified service does not exist as an installed service"

error

Any ideas how to solve this problem?

**Edit**: as far as the service panel is concerned, the MyNewService ***is*** there all the time. I restarted the PC a few times and it's there.

Comment: @Ngu Soon Hui: Please edit your question so that it contains the error message in text form - this makes it easier to find the solution with search engines, and may therefore help other people with the same problem. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

View the properties of the service and you'll see a "`Service Name`" and "`Display Name`".  The display name is the one you see in services.msc, you need to use the service name with the net command however.  Sometimes they're very different for example "`Extensible Authentication Protocol Service`" is the display name and "`EapHost`" is the service name.

Comment: Excellent, I needed this to alter my instance of sql server but couldn't get it to work! I was trying it with "SQL Server (SQLEXPRESS)" but needed MSSQL$SQLEXPRESS!

Answer (score 2):

sc delete "SERVICE NAME". Don't forget to put double quotes around the service name (if it has spaces in it). If left out it won't delete the service.

Comment: This might seem like a silly answer, but if you use single quotes instead of double quotes it doesn't work. +1 from me

Answer (score 0):

I had faced the same issue even the service name was correct. Finally I did the following

1. R-Clicked on your service name (Search 'Services' from system search bar) and found the 'Path to executable'.
2. Deleted the entry from HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services<YourServiceName>\
3. Deleted the original executable from 'Path to executable'
4. Restarted the computer.

Answer (score -3):

Here is the steps how to install, uninstall and delete the services from services.msc.

1. installutil ServiceName
2. installutil /u ServiceName
3. sc delete "ServiceName"

Note open the visual studio command prompt as an administrator and then run the above commands.

Comment: My question is about when the last step (delete "ServiceName") fails. You are not addressing my question